# Stopping Linked/Embedded Objects Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have some code in Excel which updates a Word document and then saves it depending on the information in the cells. The only issue is that occasionally there's an error which pops up

> Office is still updating linked or embedded objects for this workbook.

when the code is all completed successfully.

There are no other linked or embedded objects in the workbook.

This error was being shown when running the script manually before I added the button, so it doesn't make sense for it to be related to the button itself.

I am working on this independently meaning no others could be editing it at the same time. I click the button/run it, let it run, it freezes after closing Word (the last line of code) and then about 10secs later that error comes up.

[image: Error]

I've attempted to add `UpdateLinks:=0` and `UpdateLinks:=false` to the code but everywhere I put it it seems to not like having it there. I am not sure of how else to fix this but it cannot be an Excel/Word setting as a number of users will be utilising this.

Here's the current code:

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim msWord As Object
Dim msWordDoc As Object
Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

msWord.Visible = True
Set msWordDoc = msWord.Documents.Open("/Users/Aafrika/Desktop/Test.docx")

With msWordDoc
    With .Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting

        .Text = "<date>"
        .Replacement.Text = Format(ws.Range("C1").Value2, "dd/mm/yyyy")

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1               'wdFindContinue (WdFindWrap Enumeration)
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)

        .Text = "<amount>"
        .Replacement.Text = Format(ws.Range("C2").Value2, "currency")

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1               'wdFindContinue (WdFindWrap Enumeration)
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
    End With
    .SaveAs Filename:="/Users/Aafrika/Desktop/" & ws.Range("C3"), Password:="Password", FileFormat:=12 'wdFormatXMLDocument
    DoEvents
    .Close (False)
End With
msWord.Quit


End Sub
```

Hoping you can all shed some light on how to handle this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from Excel not being able to correctly release the Word objects. This is something that always should be done conscientiously when running another program through VBA ("automation" is one technical term used for this).

When you create objects from another program, in the background VBA creates "pointers" (links) to these objects. If they aren't expliclty released - *in the reverse order they were created* - this can "hang" VBA. There are various ways this can manifest itself - this is the first time I've seen this particular error and a quick google search doesn't turn up many examples. Possibly, this is an error that's new in Office 365/2016/2019...

The button (embedded object) has finished (reached `End Sub`) but hasn't released the objects it was working with, so Excel is waiting for that to happen.

The following code, modified from that in the question, shows how to release the objects created in the code (near the end). It involves `Set [object] = Nothing` for both the `Word.Document` and `Word.Application` objects, in the reverse order they were created at the beginning of the code.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim msWord As Object
    Dim msWordDoc As Object
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    msWord.Visible = True
    Set msWordDoc = msWord.Documents.Open("/Users/Aafrika/Desktop/Test.docx")

    With msWordDoc
          'Code here to work with the document
          'Removed to better see the problem solution
        .SaveAs Filename:="/Users/Aafrika/Desktop/" & ws.Range("C3"), Password:="Password", FileFormat:=12 'wdFormatXMLDocument
        DoEvents
        .Close (False)
    End With
'''Clean up the non-Excel objects
    Set msWordDoc = Nothing
    msWord.Quit
    Set msWord = Nothing
End Sub
```